# How can I have a group_by on one column, order_by on another column, and a filter on the 3rd different column?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is the table:

```
class APIBackoffInterrupt(Base):
    """
    When a user calls a Google API method, and it returns 403 or 429, we should apply an exponential backoff
    """
    __tablename__ = 'backoff_interrupt'
    _id = Column(Unicode(36), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Unicode(36))
    date_created_utc = Column(DateTime)
    expiry_date_utc = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    exponent = Column(Integer, default=-1)
```

I'll like to get all unique `user_id`, sorted by `date_created_utc` (desc), where `expiry_date_utc` is < the current utc now.

How can I do this?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    q1 = (session.query(APIBackoffInterrupt,
                        func.rank().over(order_by=desc(APIBackoffInterrupt.date_created_utc),
                                         partition_by=APIBackoffInterrupt.user_id).label('rnk'))
          ).subquery()
    q2 = (session.query(q1)
          .filter(q1.c.rnk == 1)
          .filter(q1.c.expiry_date_utc < datetime.datetime.utcnow())
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct user_id 
 from backoff_interrupt
   where expiry_date_utc <getdate() 
 order by date_created_utc desc
```

check this one:
updated:

```
select * into #temp from backoff_interrupt  
 where expiry_date_utc <getdate()
 order by date_created_utc desc 

  select distinct user_Id from #temp

 drop #temp
```

Comment: Invalid ORDER BY. When SELECT DISTINCT, you may only ORDER BY selected items.

Comment: i think this is wrong. gotta use window functions. ill add my own solution

Comment: for sure it is true and fast. because if using temp table. just check teh result